# AngularJS 1.5.6 - ngRepeat animations not working

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I'm having some trouble making some ng-repeat animations to work.

I have a list on a partial view where I'm making some filtering for the items on a list, and I wanted to make an animation for the filtering to make it look nice.

I have a stylesheet where i have an animation when the partial views enter and leave and that works well. Its the animation for the list that don't work, here 
are the codes:

index.html(Where i include the stylesheet):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">

        <!--Mandatory links for styles and scripts-->
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "external/semantic/semantic.css">

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "external/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type = " text/javascript" src = "external/js/jquery.md5.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "external/semantic/semantic.js"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "external/angular-1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "external/angular-1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "external/angular-1.5.6/angular-messages.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "external/angular-1.5.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "external/angular-1.5.6/angular-resource.js"></script>

        <!--Own scripts and styles-->
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "app/styles/main.css">

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "app/modules.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "app/configs/mainRoutes.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "app/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "app/controllers/courseController.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "app/services/backendServices.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app = "helperApp">
        <div data-ng-view id = "mainViews"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

selectCourse.html (Where i want the ng-repeat animation to work):

```
<div class = "ui container">
<h1 class = "ui center aligned header" id = "holaHeader">Hola</h1>
<h1 class = "ui center aligned header">Parece que no tienes cursos todavía...</h1>

<h1 class = "ui center aligned header">Ingresa un nuevo curso</h1>

<div class = "ui segments">
      <form ng-submit = "addCourse(courseName)">
        <div class="ui fluid icon input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre de nuevo curso..." ng-model = "courseName">
            <i class="search icon"></i>
        </div>
      </form>
</div>

<h1 class = "ui center aligned header">...o selecciona un curso en el cual trabajar</h1>

<div class="ui middle aligned selection list">
  <div class="item" class = "animate-repeat" ng-repeat = "course in courses | filter : courseName">
    <i class = "student icon"></i> 
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">{{course.courseName}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

main.css (Where all the styling goes, including the animations for when the partial views enter, and the animation for the list filtering):

```
body {
    background-color: #DADADA;
}

.column {
    max-width: 450px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}


#holaHeader {
    margin-top: 3.5em;
}

/*Partials enter and leave animations*/

@keyframes appear {
    from { 
        opacity: 0;  
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes disappear {
    from { 
        opacity: 1;  
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}



#mainViews.ng-enter {
    animation: 2s appear;
}

#mainViews.ng-leave {
    animation: 0.3s disappear;
}

/*Select course animations*/

.animate-repeat {
   line-height:40px;
   list-style:none;
   box-sizing:border-box;
 }

.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter,
.animate-repeat.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-move,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
  max-height:0;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave,
.animate-repeat.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.animate-repeat.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
  max-height:40px;
}
```

The main idea was to make something similar to what you can see here: http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move

Comment: Read the comments below, that styles are so old..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I was declaring the class twice on the ng-repeat...

Second, I noticed that Semantic UI classes don't get along with ng-repeat for some reason..

So I decided to put a "container" around what i wanted to repeat, add ng-repeat to it and animate that "container"

```
<div class = "animate-repeat" ng-repeat = "course in courses">
    <div class = "item">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```